# Getting Error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.Config

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am developing a spring boot project. The code works perfectly fine on localhost in  intelliJ.

The war file was created using command

`mvn clean install`

But when I run it on centos server with command

`java -jar app.war`

On running above command the deploy is successfully started at port 8080

But the problem occurs when any page containing jstl jsp is access. It displays 404 error
following error is visible on log. This code was working perfectly fine few days ago but now I cant get what changed except I made few code changes and deployed the new war file. I haven't changed anything in pom.xml.

```html
2020-07-31 13:37:27.382 ERROR 5141 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[disp                                                                                        atcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] threw exce                                                                                        ption

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/Config
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.JstlUtils.exposeLocalizationC                                                                                        ontext(JstlUtils.java:103) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView.exposeHelpers(JstlView.                                                                                        java:137) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMerge                                                                                        dOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:145) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:                                                                                        5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView                                                                                        .java:316) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherSe                                                                                        rvlet.java:1373) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResu                                                                                        lt(DispatcherServlet.java:1118) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEAS                                                                                        E]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(Dispatch                                                                                        erServlet.java:1057) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(Dispatche                                                                                        rServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(Frame                                                                                        workServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServl                                                                                        et.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat                                                                                        -embed-core-9.0.36.jar!/:9.0.36]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkSer                                                                                        vlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat                                                                                        -embed-core-9.0.36.jar!/:9.0.36]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl                                                                                        icationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar!/:9.0.36]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF                                                                                        ilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar!/:9.0.36]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.                                                                                        doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.                                                                                        3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInter                                                                                        ceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RE                                                                                        LEASE.jar!/:5.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInter                                                                                        ceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.R                                                                                        ELEASE.jar!/:5.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.                                                                                        doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.                                                                                        3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.do                                                                                        Filter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.                                                                                        jar!/:5.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.                                                                                        doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.                                                                                        3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFi                                                                                        lter(SessionManagementFilter.java:84) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:                                                                                        5.3.3.RELEASE]
```

pom.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.appl</groupId>
    <artifactId>appl</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>appll</name>
    <description>APP Search project for</description>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.hibernate </groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>

    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.darrachequesne</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa-datatables</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.12</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

> I tried both the ways w/ and w/o provided

Comment: Did you try to remove "provided" from the jstl dependency in the pom? Since you don't use an container, it is not provided by it.

Comment: @AlexFunk Yes I tried both the ways w/ and w/o provided

Comment: And error message is the same in both cases?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is that you are using the "provided" scope for your servlet. The provided scope means it will be used for build and testing but not for runtime, as it will be provided by the runtime environment (container, specific server..). You should remove the scope if you want to run it with cli.

Comment: Maybe try using the compile scope rather than provided

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to run a war file outside of a container.Remove war from POM this will set packaging to default(jar).
Then use below command in CentOS to run the project.

1. java -jar app.jar

The other solution is to install a container in CentOS and then deploy the War to it.

Comment: I think this answer needs to be upvoted. How can you run a war file outside a container?

Comment: I am able to do so. The war runs fine except the jsp part

Comment: Should I use docker for this